# #import"PGPlugin.h" "file not found" error in phonegap2.0 on xcode4.2

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode4.2, cordova-2.0.0

I am new to phonegap2.0. Now i want to create iphone app using phonegap. I am using xcode4.2 on snow leopard mac. I installed phonegap on my mac. But now i am following Embedding Cordova Webview on IOS using this below link:

```
 "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebView"
```

But when i run the coding in xcode4.2 `Iphone 5.0 Simulator`. I got  `#import"PGPlugin.h" "file not found"` error.

```
"#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
    #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
#else
    #import "PGPlugin.h"
#endif".
```

I have attached the error page Screen Shot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this part:

```
#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
    #import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
#else
    #import "PGPlugin.h"
#endif
```

with the following:

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

Also, since you're using version 2.0.0 of cordova, you may need to change everything beginning with `PG` (for example: `PGPlugin`) to `CDV` (ex: `PGPlugin` --> `CDVPlugin`).

The thing is the previous versions of plugins used to begin with `PG`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please wait. I will let you know the answer.

Comment: Let me know about your results. The thing is, since you're using version 2.0.0, sometimes you need to change several things :S

Comment: Sorry. This time i got "#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>" this error.

Comment: oh... well I'll take a closer look at your issue. Give me some time :S

Comment: Hey! it's you friend! (I've just realized it's you! XD... I answered so quickly :) ) Did you finally run a successful application with 2.0.0? I've just notice there seems to be something wrong with your file `CDVPlugin.h`. I feel like you have an old version of it? :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16678/discussion-between-gopinath-m-and-littm)

Comment: hi friend. sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hi littm. Friend how are you. Good Morning.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for the most recent versions of Cordova / Phonegap.